# Getting data into Matplot/pylab for scatter chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatter plot of some data. The data comes in the form of x and y co-ordinates in a list of lists.

stepsPlot = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [2, -1], [3, -1], [3, -2], [4, -2], [4, -1], [4, 0], [4, -1], [5, -1]]

Running the following code

```
import pylab as plt

plt.figure('Random Walk Scatter Plot')
plt.clf()
plt.title('Random Walk Scatter Plot')
plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
plt.plot(stepsPlot)
plt.show()
```

produces a graph of sorts (for testing)- so I know it's getting the data, but it doesn't understand that the data represents individual points. When I change plt.plot(stepsPlots) to plt.scatter(stepsPlot) - I assume from reading the docs that this is what I need - I get the error

> TypeError: scatter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

I assume this means that pylab doesn't understand that the data represents x and y co-ordinates?

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong? TIA

Comment: Using numpy: `import numpy as np; stepsPlot = np.array(stepsPlot); plt.plot(stepsPlot[:,0], stepsPlot[:,1], 'ro')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change two things:

- First, specify x and y axes like so:
- Second, you need to use `scatter` instead of `plot`.

So, the code should be:

```
import pylab as plt


stepsPlot = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [2, -1], [3, -1], [3, -2], [4, -2], [4, -1], [4, 0], [4, -1], [5, -1]]


plt.figure('Random Walk Scatter Plot')
plt.clf()
plt.title('Random Walk Scatter Plot')
plt.xlabel('X Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
X = [item[0] for item in stepsPlot]
Y = [item[1] for item in stepsPlot]
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

Which produces this graph:
[image]

Comment: Perfect :-) Thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help !!

Answer (score 0):

> I assume this means that pylab doesn't understand that the data
>   represents x and y co-ordinates?

Your assumption is right. You should give the plot function 2 vectors

1 containing all the X values 
2nd containing all the Y values

Answer (score 0):

@SysOverdrive mention you need to provide two vectors. One way of doing is to convert the list of list into dataframe and then provides the columns as the two vectors.

```
In [73]: df = pd.DataFrame(stepsPlot)

In [74]: df
Out[74]:
   0  1
0  1  0
1  2  0
2  2 -1
3  3 -1
4  3 -2
5  4 -2
6  4 -1
7  4  0
8  4 -1
9  5 -1

In [75]: df.columns = ['X','Y']

In [82]: import pylab as plt
    ...:
    ...: plt.figure('Random Walk Scatter Plot')
    ...: plt.clf()
    ...: plt.title('Random Walk Scatter Plot')
    ...: plt.xlabel('X Axis')
    ...: plt.ylabel('Y Axis')
    ...: plt.scatter(x=df['X'],y=df['Y'])
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]